# How does JUnit's assertArrayEquals() work?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

This is test class that uses junit4.

```
public class TestArrayUtilities {
 static final int[] ONE_D_MATRIX = { 12, 34, 45, 6, 7, 85, 67, 43 };
 static final int[] ONE_D_MATRIX_REMOVED_ONE= {12, 34, 45, 6, 85, 67, 43};
```

`removeItemWithIndex()` removes element from array with given index and return array. This test works perfectly well.

```
 @Test
public void testRemoveItemWithIndex(){
assertArrayEquals(ArrayUtilities.removeItemWithIndex(ONE_D_MATRIX, 4),ONE_D_MATRIX_REMOVED_ONE);}
```

`removeSpecifiedElementInArray()` removes element from array with specified value and return array. This test works only if it is written expilicitly. So at this example only second one works.

```
assertArrayEquals(ArrayUtilities.removeSpecifiedElementInArray(ONE_D_MATRIX, 7), ONE_D_MATRIX_REMOVED_ONE);
assertArrayEquals(ArrayUtilities.removeSpecifiedElementInArray(new int[]  { 12, 34, 45, 6, 7, 85, 67, 43 }, 7), new int[] {12, 34, 45, 6, 85, 67, 43});
```

JUnit says that :

> java.lang.AssertionError: array lengths differed, expected.length=8 actual.length=7

Is this a bug? Why don't second method work while first one do?

Comment: Did you forget to reset your arrays before each test?

Comment: Your first assumption is that an established library has a bug? What does your `removeItemWithIndex` do? What does the rest of your test do?

Comment: Why do you assume the bug is in JUnit, rather than in *your* code?

Comment: This is not my first assumption. I'm trying to understand what is going on for 3 hours. Why do first example work? @Sotirios Delimanolis

Comment: I did not know that I should reset arrays. I 'm searching now how can I do it. Thank you so much. @JNYRanger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This test works only if it is written expilicitly. So at this example only second one works.

```
assertArrayEquals(ArrayUtilities.removeSpecifiedElementInArray(ONE_D_MATRIX, 7), ONE_D_MATRIX_REMOVED_ONE);
assertArrayEquals(ArrayUtilities.removeSpecifiedElementInArray(new int[]  { 12, 34, 45, 6, 7, 85, 67, 43 }, 7), new int[] {12, 34, 45, 6, 85, 67, 43});
```

The two calls are identical, so both of them should produce the same result.

The problem is almost inevitably in the code of your tests: at some point in your code, either before or during the call of the method being tested, the array referred to as `ONE_D_MATRIX` gets mutated, which leads to the assertion error that you see.

Here is how to verify that that is indeed what is going on: add two more calls to `assertArrayEquals`, like this:

```
assertArrayEquals(ONE_D_MATRIX, new int[]  { 12, 34, 45, 6, 7, 85, 67, 43 };
int res = ArrayUtilities.removeSpecifiedElementInArray(ONE_D_MATRIX, 7);
assertArrayEquals(ONE_D_MATRIX, new int[]  { 12, 34, 45, 6, 7, 85, 67, 43 };
assertArrayEquals(res, ONE_D_MATRIX_REMOVED_ONE);
```

One of the first two assertions will fail, before you get to the actual check.

Comment: Thank you so much. This info will be salve to my newbie learner brain.@dasblinkenlight

Comment: You are exactly right. removeSpecifiedElementInArray() changes argument array its inside. And I did not know whether it is important or not.@dasblinkenlight.  I admit that I was unfair to JUnit. Sorry JUnit.